# Renderer Editor Giving Error

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer, tablemodel, tablecelleditor

I am trying my hands on a simple renderer editor from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/GetDefaultcellRenderer.htm) but my NetBeans IDE is complaining about an error in the code. Can someone help me out.

Below are the codes.

```
  public class CellEditor {

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
     public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      Object o = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
       if (o == null) {
         return Object.class;
       } else {
        return o.getClass();
      }
     }
   };
  JTable table = new JTable(model);

  model.addColumn("Boolean", new Object[] { Boolean.TRUE });
 model.addColumn("Date", new Object[] { new Date() });
 model.addColumn("Double", new Object[] { new Double(Math.PI) });
 model.addColumn("Float", new Object[] { new Float(1.2) });
 model.addColumn("Icon", new Object[] { new ImageIcon("icon.gif") });
 model.addColumn("Number", new Object[] { new Integer(1) });
 model.addColumn("Object", new Object[] { "object" });

  Enumeration e = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
   TableColumn col = (TableColumn) e.nextElement();

    col.setCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class)); //IDE complains cannot find 
      method setCellRenderer
    col.setCellEditor(table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));   // IDE complains cannot find 
      method setCellEditor

  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  f.setSize(300,300);
  f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
  f.setVisible(true);
   }
 }
```

thanks to all.

Comment: Your indentation is not uniform, making your code very hard to read. If you're mixing spaces with tabs, avoid this, and use spaces only. Please fix your code and post your complete error messages too.

Comment: Important: show your imports too as they may have bearing on your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TableColumn` is a class of `JavaFX` as well as `swing`. Check that you're using the `swing` import

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
```

Hints:
Use `<alt><enter>` for the IDE to automatically find the imports.

Place your cursor immediately after `col.` to find the methods of the class. You can also press `<ctl><space>` with your cursor after `col.`

Comment: Maybe a better guess than mine. 1+

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks good and *should* compile. A guess: do you have your own class called TableColumn? If so, it will shadow the Java core class TableColumn and prevent your code from compiling. If so, rename your class to something else that does not clash with the core Java class name.

Also and as per my comments, show your imports too as they may have bearing on your problem.

---

As an aside, here's your code formatted correctly. Notice that it's easier to read since you know precisely where methods and blocks begin and end:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class CellEditor {

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
         public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            Object o = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
            if (o == null) {
               return Object.class;
            } else {
               return o.getClass();
            }
         }
      };
      JTable table = new JTable(model);

      model.addColumn("Boolean", new Object[] { Boolean.TRUE });
      model.addColumn("Date", new Object[] { new Date() });
      model.addColumn("Double", new Object[] { new Double(Math.PI) });
      model.addColumn("Float", new Object[] { new Float(1.2) });
      model.addColumn("Icon", new Object[] { new ImageIcon("icon.gif") });
      model.addColumn("Number", new Object[] { new Integer(1) });
      model.addColumn("Object", new Object[] { "object" });

      Enumeration e = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
      TableColumn col = (TableColumn) e.nextElement();

      // IDE complains cannot find method setCellRenderer
      col.setCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class)); 

      // IDE complains cannot find method setCellEditor
      col.setCellEditor(table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class)); 

      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setSize(300, 300);
      f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the formatting advise. Will start to adopt this style

Comment: @CodeAngel: you're welcome and glad you've found your problem and solved it! Note that most modern IDE's such as Eclipse, NetBeans and IntelliJ Idea will format your code for you if you wish.